# multipart embedded images not working in email clients (works in GMail)

Tags: php, email, html-email, email-attachments, email-client

I am using the code below to attach and embed an image into an email. This works in Gmail which I originally thought would be the biggest hurdle. For some reason though, when I access the email via Apple Mail and Thunderbird (same account), the image does not load but shows the following respectively:

[image: Apple Mail][image: Thunderbird]

What am I doing wrong? I cannot host and link these images normally as they are data driven graphs that are generated on the fly. Multipart attachment style embedding seems like my only option.

```
$to      = "...";

$body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body><img src="cid:image"/></body></html>';

$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());

// headers
$headers  = "From: ..." . $eol;
$headers .= "Reply-To: ..." . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;

// message
$message  = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$message .= $body . $eol;

// attachment
$filename = "image.png";
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));

$message .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"image.png\"" . $eol;
$message .= "Content-ID: <image>" . $eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"image.png\"" . $eol;
$message .= $content . $eol;
$message .= "--" . $separator . "--";

mail($to, "test", $message, $headers);
```